# InvalidVariant Exception Thrown

Tags: c#, exception

I made an Excel Formula in `C#` which was working fine. Then I called a function in my code which was expecting an object type parameter. I passed an integer array in it. After running the formula again this message was shown in my `Visual Studio`.

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'InvalidVariant' 
>     Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'InvalidVariant' : 'An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss.'

Edit: I tried this:

```
int[] nodeArr = new int[] { n.NodeNo };

object obj = nodeArr;

OSIObj.Geometry.UpdateGroup(n.Group, 2, 1, ref obj);
```

**UpdateGroup expects:**

```
int UpdateGroup (string szGroupNames, int nFlag, int nEntity, ref object nEntityArray);
```

I need to know if passing integer array to a object parameter is causing this error or is there something else I am missing out?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we cant help you debug what we cant see.

Comment: is n.group a string?